# FATAL EXCEPTION: ParseRequest.NETWORK_EXECUTOR-thread-60

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am getting this error in my Activity where I use Parse SDK. The whole code is [here](http://pastie.org/9689377), but the code is huge and the crash is not even giving me the line of code where it is occuring. I searched a lot but found nothing about this error. Can anyone tell me what exactly this error means?

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: I notice that you do a query inside AsyncTask, think this might hurt the Thread management.

Comment: @cYrixmorten But why? I am querying in background thread.

Comment: My concern is that if you mistakenly fire any of the AsyncTask's two times. Just know that I once put the pinning of some of my objects in a synchronized method, which was enough to make it randomly hang infinitely. Besides, they provide good queryInBackground methods, now also supporting Bolt, so see no reason to try and enforce AsyncTask? Not that I am sure that is the cause of error though, just a strong suspicion.

Comment: @cYrixmorten So, querying in async is the cause or pinning or both?

Comment: I would not do any of those in AsyncTask. What is the reason for you wanting to do so btw?

Comment: @cYrixmorten Well no specific reason. I will change it to query in background. But I need to use "loadPicsInBg" async.

Comment: @cYrixmorten Well the reason was I am querying two things at once. You can see query.find() and query2.find().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since adding a code example, I will write an answer.

You are using AsyncTask to do multiple queries and to know when these finish.

Parse recently added Bolts to their API (1.7.0 or 1.7.1) https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android

With Bolts you can do the same as you can with Promises in javascript, in case you are familiar with that.

A simple example deleting all objects matching a query:

```
findAsync(query).continueWithTask(new Continuation<List<ParseObject>, Task<Void>>() {
  public Task<Void> then(Task<List<ParseObject>> results) throws Exception {
    // Collect one task for each delete into an array.
    ArrayList<Task<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<Task<Void>>();
    for (ParseObject result : results) {
      // Start this delete immediately and add its task to the list.
      tasks.add(deleteAsync(result));
    }
    // Return a new task that will be marked as completed when all of the deletes are
    // finished.
    return Task.whenAll(tasks);
  }
}).onSuccess(new Continuation<Void, Void>() {
  public Void then(Task<Void> ignored) throws Exception {
    // Every comment was deleted.
    return null;
  }
});
```

The `return Task.whenAll(tasks);` returns a task that fires `onSuccess` only when all the tasks in the `tasks` arraylist has completed.

Not only does this rely on Parse´ own background management, this example also makes all the tasks run in parallel, so is generally faster.

In your situation, you would simple need to create an ordinary method that:

- Use the new built-in functions to return a task for both `query1` and `query2`
- Add those to an arraylist of tasks
- return Task.whenAll(tasks)

Lets say this method is `loadPicsInBg`, then to use it:

```
loadPicsInBg().onSuccess(new Continuation<Void, Void>() {
  public Void then(Task<Void> ignored) throws Exception {
    // all the queries completed
    return null;
  }
});
```

I know this is a huge refactor and maybe you can do fine with the simpler callback approach, but Bolt indeed gives more power over the complex queries if used correctly. Furthermore it avoids the problem with nested queries creating a ever increasing indentation in the code making it difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was loadPicsInBg(). Whenever I restarted activity, I guess the threads were increasing. And finally after 4-5 restarts of activity, it crashed.

Comment: Had a feeling that it had something to do with that :) glad I could help